# Comentários a resposta fora de contexto

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, comentários

Respondi a uma questão e passado um tempo corrigi um erro de um termo que coloquei na resposta.

Nesse mesmo dia tive comentários ao que respondi argumentando. No entretanto a pessoa que os realizou resolveu atacar-me pessoalmente com comentários pessoais para além de realizar comentários técnicos. Em consequência esse interveniente apagou os seus comentários presentes na minha resposta.

Pergunto se devo de apagar os meus comentários presentes nessa resposta sendo que ficam fora de contexto após o mesmo ter apagado os seus comentários.

Comment: Se estão fora de contexto, sim. Se acha que algum acrescenta algo importante, tente inserir essa informação na própria resposta.

Comment: chambelix, se os comentários não ajudarem em nada na pergunta/resposta só estão a fazer "ruído" por isso mais vale apagar após o AP ou AR verem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não vi estes comentários então vou tentar responder genericamente.

O ideal é que apague. Se falta informações para entender a conversa, não tem serventia deixar lá. Principalmente se estes comentários não estão ajudando a melhorar a compreensão da postagem principal. Como ficaram só os seus, se tiver alguma coisa importante na resposta, edite a resposta colocando esta informação relevante.

É normal apagar comentários que não façam mais sentido, que serviam a um propósito momentâneo. Até gostaria que isto fosse feito com mais intensidade (até mesmo eu deveria fazer). Comentários que se tornam "conversas" e não ajudam a postagem no futuro deveriam ser sempre apagados. Também não é o fim do mundo se ficarem.

Comment: Nem mais bigown

Comment: ok...apagarei então e obrigado pela resposta. Lamento mas apenas tenho um mês aqui no stack...pelo certamente voltarei a ter duvidas deste género.

Comment: @chambelix não há problemas, o meta está aqui para isto. Ninguém nasce sabendo. O importante é ir melhorando sempre.